# How can i create multiple markers on a google map?

Tags: meteor

I need to show multiple pointers based on the given latitude and longitude values.I did one sample but it comes only one pointers.As shown code below.

Meteor Js Code :

this are my objects

```
var latlong1 = {

      lat: 17.385044,

      long: 78.486671

    }

    console.log("* 2 *");



    var latlong2 = {

      lat: 16.306652,

      long: 80.436540

    }



    var latlong3 = {

      lat:15.505723,

      long: 80.049922

    }



    var latlong4 = {

      lat: 15.317277,

      long: 75.713888

    }
```

i know i can create it like this.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),

        map: map,

        draggable: true,

        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

        icon: icon

      });
```

and use values inside the position

```
new google.maps.LatLng(latlong3.lat, latlong3.long)
```

But there is another way?

Comment: Pretty please use [English function names](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-ugly-american-programmer/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first Create an array based on that object values.

```
var latLong =[];
```

and lester create a simple function.

```
function createMarkers(){
  for(var i = 0 ; i <latLong.length ; i++) {
      lat = latLong[i].lat;
      long = latLong[i].long;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
        map: map,
        icon: 'http://Yourimagesourcehere'
      });
    }
}
```

Test and tell me.