# Get google map Markers location in Meteor js

Tags: meteor

I need to know about to get google map points location in Meteor JS.**For example in my map showing 10 pointers based on location latitude and longitude.When ever click a marker then shows location based on that pointer in a new window(or popup)**.

I didn't get any idea about this.So please suggest me what to do for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help: [Google Maps with Meteor and a reactive InfoWindow]()http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774565/google-maps-with-meteor-and-a-reactive-infowindow?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here its an [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows), wich have the `content` option.

So lets say you have this simple initialize function

```
  initializeMap = function() {
     //Common code to init the map.

     //common code to create dynamic markers already give you an answer here
     //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424854/how-can-i-create-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map
     //now on the same function lets add this code

   function createMarkers(){

       for(var i = 0 ; i <latLong.length ; i++) {

          //lati and long are declared as global variables.
          lati = latLong[i].lat;
          longi = latLong[i].long;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi),
               map: map,
               icon: 'http://Yourimagesourcehere'
           });

       //and this is how you call it.
        myInfoWindow(marker2,map,lati,long); 
      }

      //Function to created infoWindows.

    function myInfoWindow(marker2,map,lati,long){

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'mouseover', function() {
           for(var i=0;i<markerArray.length;i++){
               infoWindow.setContent( 'My lat is ' + lati + "my long is " + longi );
              infoWindow.open(map, marker2);
           }});
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'mouseout', function() {
           infoWindow.close();
         } 
       }
    }
```

So like you see based on the other question [How can i create multiple markers on a google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424854/how-can-i-create-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map), in this example we added the new function named `myInfoWindow` with 4 parameters, the `marker`,the `map`, and the 2 variables for the content (in this case `late`,`long`)

If you have doubts about how to init the map or how the code should look i have this [DEMO](http://ethaan-map.meteor.com) and here is the [Source Code](https://github.com/Ethaan/Meteorjs-sample-map), just add the `infoWindow` function inside the `createMarkers` function and it should work.
Tell me if Works.